# Passing variables to a view using Asp.net mvc and jQuery load()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm currently loading a view(ascx) into a div using jQuery load(). I want to pass some variables to the view when loading it though so i'm using $.load(view, data); This does not seem to cause any problems but i have no idea how to access the Json object i'm passing in to the control.

Here is the jQuery:

```
var val = {"Id":"1"};
$("#DynamicForm").empty().load('/controller/view', val);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case jQuery issues a POST request:

```
POST /controller/view HTTP/1.1
...

Id=1
```

So, you can access the Id parameter as `Request.Form["Id"]`, or just as an action parameter:

```
public class Controller...
{
    public ActionResult Index(string Id) { ... }
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct.

But I found that if you're relying on Json returned from asp.net "return Json(Id=1)" you need to parse the object through the Json plugin to convert it back to the correct object format. $.evalJSON(val)